# Applying multiple simaltaneous rotations to same figure

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have a simple rectangular shape in my application which I am rotating fixing one of its side, and rotating around the X axis. The rotation looks something like the following figure (grey denotes the current rotation that I am getting with this figure)

[image]

I am using the following code to get this rotation

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(position of the axis point which has to be fixed for rotation);
glRotatef(rotationAmount, 1,0,0);
glTranslatef(-position of the axis point which has to be fixed for rotation);
Rectangle(xPosition, Position,200,100);
glPopMatrix();
```

However, I have to rotate this same figure with an additional rotation around y axis around one of its side (green arrow direction in the figure). How do I rotate this rectangle such that it keeps on rotating around x-axis and around y-axis simaltaneously?

EDIT:
I did try adding another `glRotatef(rotateAroundYaxis amount,0,1,0)` but the output does not actually looks like what I was expecting. The figure rotates in two quadrants instead of rotating around y-axis like a simple page turn.

While if I try these two rotations independently using only one of them in the program (not both of them together), i.e.

```
glRotatef(rotateAmount,1,0,0);
glRotatef(rotateYamount,0,-1,0);
```

I do get the required X and Y rotations independently, but when together, it combines into some weird rotation effect.

Comment: Don't use the fixed function pipeline!

Comment: @FelixK. That would be what you tell someone who already has experience with OpenGL, not a beginner.

Comment: @eznme No, why learn something which is really outdated and switch over later? There are some really good tutorials on OpenGL-VertexBuffers, Shaders and other techniques which are not really new!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the following. If you dont please tell and i will change it.

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(position of the axis point which has to be fixed for rotation);
glRotatef(rotationAmount, 1,0,0); // <- keep this but also
glRotatef(rotationAmountAroundYAxis, 0,1,0); // <- add this
glTranslatef(-position of the axis point which has to be fixed for rotation);
Rectangle(xPosition, Position,200,100);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I obviously did try the same but was getting weird roation instead of just simple rotation aroung X and Y respectively. Here's a screenshot of what I am getting after adding `rotationAmountAroundYAxis` http://i.imgur.com/9G2TC.png

Comment: Editted and added the info to the question

Comment: Cannot see the coordinate-system in your screenshot but it looks correct (assuming certain coordinate directions). If this is not what you expected then the problem is probably not the 2 rotations but the rotation of your coordinate system or camera-point as a whole (outside of the push/pop).

Comment: Added the axes to the screenshot if that conveys some more info. http://i.imgur.com/3S4Uw.png

Comment: to the edit in your question: of course it rotates through the quadrant, this is absolutely expected. The only way to change that would be to complete the first rotation-animation before starting the second rotation-animation. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. I think I probably asked the wrong in the wrong sense saying `simaltaneously` but first rotating around `X` and then afterwards around `Y` would be the correct way. How will that be done with one rectangle here?

Comment: first animate increasing `rotationAmount` for each frame, then when that is done (e.g. after 2 seconds) start increasing rotationAmountAroundYAxis each frame. When that is done keep the angles the way they are until no more frames have to be rendered.

Comment: If I keep both the rotations in the the same `Push Pop Matrix` block, I won't get the required effect. If I separately try to rotate around X and Y in different `Push Pops`, I would have to draw another figure which again is what I don't want. In fact, in the last part of the question, I was trying to convey the same about how to give this `X` and `Y` rotation (not simaltaneously though). What's the solution to this thing?

Comment: First animating the rotation all along the X-axis and then separately doing the Y-rotation is actually not what I would want to do. To get this simultaneous rotation effect, a more natural thing looks like rotating around X, then rotating around Y afterwards, then X and so on. But the question would remain on howto implement that?

Comment: This might be obvious but just to be certain that we are talking about the same thing: What you write between begin/end is only a single frame of the animation and to animate it you need an outside loop that calls this multiple times and calls an OS-dependent SwapBuffers-function.

Comment: That's right. I didn't introduce the term `openFrameworks` here which is what I am using for graphics and other things. In `openFrameworks` the `draw` function gets called in a continuous loop inside which I am animating these figures. Each time the draw function is called, I mention the updated `rotationAmount` for the figure in a `Push Pop` block. This is what I am doing for single rotations i.e. only X or only Y (not able to figure out what to be done for two rotations one after the other on the same object in a single draw function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this :

```
glRotatef(rotationAmount, 1,0,0);
```

into this :

```
glRotatef(rotationAmount, 1,1,0);
```

Comment: Editted and added the info to the question.